# How can I add annotation on xaxis/yaxis using shinobiCharts

Tags: ios, iphone, shinobi

I am trying to add annotations on chart axis , but annotation always gets clipped by the axis and I cannot place them on the axis besides the tickLabels.

[image]

Comment: How you are adding annotations ? can you please share with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the clipping occurs is because the annotations are placed on a view which has `clipsToBounds` set to `YES`.

To change this:

```
chart.canvas.glView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

To enable this to compile, you'll have to import `SChartCanvas.h`

```
#import <ShinobiControls/SChartCanvas.h>
```

Hope that helps

sam